# Adding 95% confidence intervals to the generated Kaplan Meier curves for competing risk (using ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I used the code below for competing risk obtained from this site ([link](https://www.emilyzabor.com/tutorials/survival_analysis_in_r_tutorial.html)).
This is my [dataframe](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZclo5XZsaHsklotYOuWI33s2UyArY83sG9k).

I want to

1. **Add 95% confidence interval** to the generated Kaplan Meier curves for competing risk
   I googled it but I couldn't figure it out.I am aware how to add 95%CI to regular KM curves but not competing risk related KM curves.
2. make the end point for x axis is 120 months without compromising patients at risk (I did it in the regular way but number of patients at risk was missed up).

Appreciate your help and cooperation

This is my output:
[image]
Used code:

```
#=======================================================================
## Late reop
library(survival);library(survminer);library(Hmisc);library(ggplot2)
ci_ulcer <- cuminc(data$OS.reop.months, 
                   data$status_dead1_reop2, 
                   data$Groups_Extensive1.Conservative0,cencode = 0 ); ci_ulcer[["Tests"]]
##=======================================================================
ciplotdat2 <-
  ci_ulcer %>%
  list_modify("Tests" = NULL) %>%
  map_df(`[`, c("time", "est"), .id = "id") %>%
  filter(id %in% c("0 2", "1 2")) %>%
  mutate(Approach = recode(
    id,"0 2" = "Conservative",
    "1 2" = "Extensive"))
##=======================================================================
## Add the numbers at risk table 
mel_plot <- ggplot(ciplotdat2, aes(x = time, y = est, color = Approach)) +
  geom_step(lwd = 1.2) +
  ylim(c(0, 1)) +
  #coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 120)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 260, 24)) +
  geom_step(size = 1.5) + theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14),
  legend.title = element_blank(),
  legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x = "Months",
       y = "Cumulative incidence",
       title = "Late reoperation by Approach") +
  annotate("text", x = 0, y = 1, hjust = 0,
           label = paste0(
             "p-value = ",
             ifelse(ci_ulcer$Tests[2, 2] < .001,  
                    "<.001",
                    round(ci_ulcer$Tests[2, 2], 3)))) 

#=============================================================
mel_fit <- survfit(Surv(data$OS.reop.months,
                        ifelse(data$status_dead1_reop2 != 0, 1, 0)) ~ Groups_Extensive1.Conservative0, data = data)

num <- ggsurvplot(fit = mel_fit,
                  risk.table = T,
                  risk.table.y.text = F,ylab = "Months",
                  break.x.by =24,
                  xscale = "m_y",# will transform labels from months to years
                  tables.theme = theme_cleantable( ), #?theme_cleantable
                  #tables.theme = theme_survminer(font.main = 10),
                  risk.table.fontsize = 3, data=data)

cowplot::plot_grid(mel_plot,num$table,nrow = 2,rel_heights = c(4, 1),
                   align = "v",axis = "b")
```

Comment: can you share `ci_ulcer`?

Comment: @Werner Added. Thanks for noticing that. Upvoted!